# MVC 4 Authorize and Login usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm unexperienced with MVC, and I'm trying to create a project with a main index page and various subpages, all of which requires the user to be logged, and a login/register page that is the entry point for everyone.

I was looking for how to check and redirect the user to the login page when they try to access the other pages directly, or when the session variable expires, and I'm doing this:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

And I'm expecting that, if the user isn't logged in, they're redirected to `~/Home/Login`, but I don't think this is happening and I'm getting errors in these pages since I'm trying to use the Session variable for displaying their username in the page etc

In the login code, I have:

```
//after I found the user in my database and confirmed his password
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.userName, false);

Session["User"] = user;
return View("Index");
```

I've found various solutions on how to implement custom authorizations, logins and such, but I don't know if those solutions are already available on this MVC version (I'm using 4.0) and I'd like to keep it to the simplest way possible since I'm still learning.

So basically I want to do a check if the user is logged on all pages but the login one, and if he isn't, redirect him to the login page.

How can I accomplish this using the MVC features?

Answer (score 1):

On your Login Action Methods you need to decorate with [AlloyAnonymous].  Drop the concept of Session from your authentication/authorization.  You don't need store the user object in session, it will be stored in the HttpContext already.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've seen some guides explaining that one way is so every controller/method is auto-set to authorized only, and instead I specify which ones are allowed to be called anonymously, but I couldn't find where I set this.

Comment: You set which methods are allowed anonymously by the attribute i mentioned.  Inversely if you want to specify which methods require authorization you use the [Authorize] attribute in combination with whatever role you require like [Authorize("ADMINS")]

Comment: Ah, I don't have to configure it... that's great. I'm still having issues though, my routing config is default to "Index" function. My `Home` has the `Index` with the `[Authorize]` attribute, which I'd like to send the user (not logged) to `~/Home/Login` as specified in my web.config, but it's not working... it's still going through the `Index` function as if the `[Authorize]` isn't working. Would you know why is this happening?

Comment: Remove the [Authorize] attribute from above the controller declaration and put it a top the Index method.  Put [AllowAnonymous] above the controller decoration to allow access to the Login action.  Or better still put all your login/logout logic in a separate controller (the default MVC templates will create one for you called "AccountController"), just spin up a test MVC project and steal it out of there